# "Debugging lambda expressions with Visual Studio" no longer working?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2015, support for debugging lambda expressions was introduced: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/support-for-debugging-lambda-expressions-with-visual-studio-2015/

However, I've never been able to get this to work in Visual Studio 2017, nor in the new Visual Studio 2019.

In 2019, I get: "Error: Inspecting the state of an object in the debuggee of type System.Reflection.PropertyInfo is not supported in this context".

Did this functionality get removed?

Example: I am debugging code with a variable "tags" that contains an `IQueryable`. I want to check the `Name` property of every item, so in the Immediate Window or Watch window I write: `tags.Select(t => t.Name)`. Then the error.

Comment: Can you add a simple example?

Comment: @stuart: Added for your pleasure.

Comment: please show some data

Comment: @Ravi: This is not a specific problem, it is a question about a functionality in general. In the example, the data is a collection of object "Tag"; "Tag" has a property "Name".

Comment: @Protectorone Does it work if you try an `IEnumerable` instead of an `IQueryable`?

Comment: @Protectorone Did u check whether it is in release mode?

Comment: @AderbalFarias: Interesting! It indeed works on a native `IEnumerable`! It doesn't work on an IQueryable `AsEnumerable()`, though, but it will work with `ToArray`!

Comment: @Avinash: I am definitely in Debug.

Comment: First even if the feature has been introduce in vs 2015, the debugging experience is not the same in 2017/2019. There could be many reasons, but here I can't give a true answer without a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a temporary answer without background until someone with knowledge comes along.

If you call `ToArray` on the `IQueryable`, you can use lambdas in debugging on that. It doesn't work on the `AsEnumerable` result though, so it doesn't simply seem to be about using `IEnumerable` methods vs. `IQueryable` methods.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can use an Immediate window to explore the value. Consider the simple code here:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   int[] Numbers = { 10, 20, 30, 40 };

   var NewNumbers = Numbers.Select(x => x * x);
}
```

Put a debug point where your lambda expression is and open the Debug -> Window -> Immediate.

In the Immediate window, you can write the expression you want to test and see the result. I typed:

```
Numbers.Select(x => x*x)
```

Press enter, you will see the result as :

```
Count = 4
    [0]: 100
    [1]: 400
    [2]: 900
    [3]: 1600
```

An Immediate window is a playground to check variables, run expressions, and helps to debug faster.

Answer (score -1):

This was caused by a missing feature in the new debug engine Microsoft had introduced, apparently. Following instructions from [this link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/switching-to-managed-compatibility-mode-in-visual-studio-2013/) I got things to work. The instructions boil down to:

1. From the "Tools" menu open "Options".
2. On the left hand side pick "Debugging", "General".
3. Scroll all the way down to check "Use
   Managed Compatibility Mode".

Comment: I read this too, but this is about 2013! I want functionality from _2015_ to work in _2019_!

Comment: There's no such an option as "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" in 2019